# Breadcrumb style with WPF-ListView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, styles

I want to create a simple breadcrumb bar with ListView. Following a simple wireframe screenshot what I would like to archive in the future:

[image: This is what I am looking for]

Now, I already created already some code, mainly doing it with DataTemplates, which works actually quite well, but I have some visual problems I am not able to solve:

[image: This is what I currently achieved]

- Main problem concerns the different width of the items. The center of an "arrow" should be stretched and the tail and head should be a fixed width...
- The other problem is the visual style of the first and last items

Here's the actual code:

```
<ListView DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding TagList}"
                MinWidth="300" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="8,0,0,0">

                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="-8,0,0,0">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFC64242" Data="F1 M 112,144L 104,144L 112,160L 104,176L 112,176" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Rectangle Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFC64242" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Margin="0.5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto"/>
                                        <Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 128,144L 160,144" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto"/>
                                        <Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 128,176L 160,176" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Path Stretch="Fill" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#FFC64242" Data="F1 M 168,144L 176,160L 168,176" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2" d:LayoutOverrides="GridBox"/>
                                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left"  FontSize="12" Content="{Binding Content, FallbackValue=Tagname n/a}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Margin="8,0"/>
                                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="X" Background="Transparent" FontSize="12" Command="{Binding RemoveTagBtn}" Grid.Column="0" Width="13.077" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                                        <!--<Border Background="#FFf7f7f7" BorderBrush="#FFc9c9c9" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,5.96" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>     -->
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Comment: do you want each item (i.e. label within the dockpanel) to have fixed width? what is tail and head here? and how are visual styles of first and last item different?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now as I had to find an answer myself in short time, this is my current solution. Also if you do not need the "selectable" feature of ListBox, you can exchange it with ItemControl.

[image: Current solution for the problem]

Here's the code. Please be aware that I've commented out the "IsSelected" Triggers for the ItemStyleContainer...

```
 <ListBox Padding="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding TagList}"
                MinWidth="300" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="8,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource LXBarButtonBackgroundNormal}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource LXBarButtonBorderNormal}"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">

                                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="-8,0,0,0">
                                            <Path DockPanel.Dock="Left"  Stroke="{DynamicResource LXBarButtonBorderNormal}" Fill="{DynamicResource LXBarButtonBackgroundNormal}" Data="F1 M 112,144L 104,144L 112,160L 104,176L 112,176" Stretch="Fill" Height="32" Width="8" />  
                                            <Path DockPanel.Dock="Right" Stroke="{DynamicResource LXBarButtonBorderNormal}" Fill="{DynamicResource LXBarButtonBackgroundNormal}" Data="F1 M 168,144L 176,160L 168,176" Stretch="Fill" Height="32" Width="8" />
                                            <Border Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" BorderThickness="0,1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                      <ContentPresenter />
                                                    <!--
                                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                      <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background"
                                                                Value="Blue"/>
                                                      </Trigger>
                                                      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                                                Value="Red"/>
                                                      </Trigger>
                                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    -->
                                            </Border>
                                        </DockPanel>

                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30">
                                        <local:LXImageButton BorderThickness="0" Style="{DynamicResource LXBarImageButton}" Padding="0"  DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding RemoveTagBtn}" Height="16" Width="16"
                                        NormalImage="/com.example.Views;component/Resources/Icons/Buttons/btnCloseXS_normal.png"
                                        ActiveImage="/com.example.Views;component/Resources/Icons/Buttons/btnCloseXS_active.png"
                                        HoverImage="/com.example.Views;component/Resources/Icons/Buttons/btnCloseXS_hover.png"
                                        PressedImage="/com.example.Views;component/Resources/Icons/Buttons/btnCloseXS_hover.png"
                                        DisabledImage="/com.example.Views;component/Resources/Icons/Buttons/btnCloseXS_passive.png"
                                         />
                                        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left"  FontSize="12" Content="{Binding Content, FallbackValue=Tagname n/a}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </DockPanel>   
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a custom shape that renders the arrow that you want.
I used some code from the `Rectangle` class.

As for the part of styling the first and last elements. You will need some sort of `AttachedBehavior` that adjusts some property based on the item index.

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace CustomShapes
{
    public class SquaredArrow : Shape
    {
        protected Rect _rect = Rect.Empty;

        #region TipOffset

        /// <summary>
        /// TipOffset Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TipOffsetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TipOffset", typeof(double), typeof(SquaredArrow),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((double)10, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the TipOffset property.  This dependency property 
        /// indicates ....
        /// </summary>
        [System.ComponentModel.Category("SquaredArrow")]
        public double TipOffset
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(TipOffsetProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TipOffsetProperty, value); }
        }

        #endregion

        public SquaredArrow()
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            r.Measure(new Size(100, 100));
            r.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
        }

        static SquaredArrow()
        {
            StretchProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SquaredArrow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Stretch.Fill));

        }

        protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
        {
            get { return CreateShape(); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return the transformation applied to the geometry before rendering
        /// </summary> 
        public override Transform GeometryTransform
        {
            get
            {
                return Transform.Identity;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is where the arrow shape is created.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Geometry CreateShape()
        {
            double width = _rect.Width;
            double height = _rect.Height;

            double borderOffset = GetStrokeThickness() / 2d;

            PathGeometry g = new PathGeometry();

            PathFigure figure = new PathFigure();
            figure.IsClosed = true;
            figure.StartPoint = new Point(borderOffset, borderOffset);

            figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(width - TipOffset + borderOffset, borderOffset), true));
            figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(width + borderOffset, height / 2d + borderOffset), true));
            figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(width + borderOffset - TipOffset, height + borderOffset), true));
            figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(borderOffset, height + borderOffset), true));

            g.Figures.Add(figure);

            return g;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates DesiredSize of the Rectangle.  Called by parent UIElement.  This is the first pass of layout. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="constraint">Constraint size is an "upper limit" that Rectangle should not exceed.</param>
        /// <returns>Rectangle's desired size.</returns>
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            if (Stretch == Stretch.UniformToFill)
            {
                double width = constraint.Width;
                double height = constraint.Height;

                if (Double.IsInfinity(width) && Double.IsInfinity(height))
                {
                    return GetNaturalSize();
                }
                else if (Double.IsInfinity(width) || Double.IsInfinity(height))
                {
                    width = Math.Min(width, height);
                }
                else
                {
                    width = Math.Max(width, height);
                }

                return new Size(width, width);
            }

            return GetNaturalSize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the final size of the shape and cachnes the bounds. 
        /// </summary>
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            // Since we do NOT want the RadiusX and RadiusY to change with the rendering transformation, we
            // construct the rectangle to fit finalSize with the appropriate Stretch mode.  The rendering 
            // transformation will thus be the identity.

            double penThickness = GetStrokeThickness();
            double margin = penThickness / 2;

            _rect = new Rect(
                margin, // X 
                margin, // Y
                Math.Max(0, finalSize.Width - penThickness),    // Width 
                Math.Max(0, finalSize.Height - penThickness));  // Height

            switch (Stretch)
            {
                case Stretch.None:
                    // A 0 Rect.Width and Rect.Height rectangle 
                    _rect.Width = _rect.Height = 0;
                    break;

                case Stretch.Fill:
                    // The most common case: a rectangle that fills the box.
                    // _rect has already been initialized for that.
                    break;

                case Stretch.Uniform:
                    // The maximal square that fits in the final box 
                    if (_rect.Width > _rect.Height)
                    {
                        _rect.Width = _rect.Height;
                    }
                    else  // _rect.Width <= _rect.Height
                    {
                        _rect.Height = _rect.Width;
                    }
                    break;

                case Stretch.UniformToFill:
                    // The minimal square that fills the final box
                    if (_rect.Width < _rect.Height)
                    {
                        _rect.Width = _rect.Height;
                    }
                    else  // _rect.Width >= _rect.Height 
                    {
                        _rect.Height = _rect.Width;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return finalSize;
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Get the natural size of the geometry that defines this shape
        /// </summary> 
        protected Size GetNaturalSize()
        {
            double strokeThickness = GetStrokeThickness();
            return new Size(strokeThickness, strokeThickness);
        }

        protected double GetStrokeThickness()
        {
            return this.StrokeThickness;
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// Render callback.
        /// </summary> 
        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Stroke, GetStrokeThickness());

            drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Fill, pen, DefiningGeometry);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. As I was looking into a "visual" solution in XAML I did not test yours. Sorry - but maybe others are interested in the different solutions...