# Name of a UI component

Tags: wpf, user-interface

anyone knows the name of the UI component you see below? I want to use something like that in my WPF application.

Does DevExpress have something like that or any free component library?

**Note**: Yes it is funny, and yes my drawing sucks.

[image]

Comment: Something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727382/breadcrumb-style-with-wpf-listview

Comment: Make your own component, it is not so complicated.

Comment: @Alex, Yep that is an option but I want it to be in sync with DevExpress themes.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a specific look on Breadcrumbs. DevExpress probably got Breadcrumbs

Comment: @IngoVals Nop, DevExpress does not have this control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Called [**Breadcrumbs**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_%28navigation%29) for whatever reason.